# node cluster fork executes code too often

Tags: node.js, worker

I have jobs (functions) that I want to execute in separate threads. I have therefore created a utility function to do so:

```
import {cpus} from "os"
import cluster from 'cluster'

export default function runInThread(func: Function, useAllCores = false, numThreads = useAllCores ? cpus().length : 1) {
    if(cluster.isMaster) {
        for(let i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
            cluster.fork()
        }
    } else {
        func()
    }
}
```

then I want to execute the jobs like this:

```
import runInThread from "../helpers/threading"
import job1 from "./job1"
import job2 from "./job2"

let jobs = [
    job1, 
    job2
]

jobs.forEach(job => runInThread(job))
```

The example jobs are:

```
export default function job1() {
    console.log('job1')
}

export default function job2() {
    console.log('job2')
}
```

Unfortunately they seem to get executed twice, since the output is:

```
job1
job1
job2
job2
```

So it seems that every job gets forked twice...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main idea - each thread (fork) like host for certain function. In example this is just function name, but in real work you can generate some id for function and pass it to worker as env variable.

```
import {cpus} from "os"
import cluster from 'cluster'

export default function runInThread(func: Function, useAllCores = false, numThreads = useAllCores ? cpus().length : 1) {
    if(cluster.isMaster) {
        for(let i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
            cluster.fork({FUNC_ID: func.name})
        }
    } else {
       if (process.env.FUNC_ID === func.name) {
         func()
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you described it totally normal. And only two workers are spawned.

You can confirm this by printing the worker id in your jobs:

```
import cluster from 'cluster';

export default function job1() {
  console.log(`WORKER #${cluster.worker.id}: job1`);
};
```

Once you call fork, it spawns a new node.js process (not a thread by the way) and executes your code again. That means each one of your workers will effectively execute something like the following:

```
import {cpus} from "os"
import cluster from 'cluster'
import job1 from "./job1"
import job2 from "./job2"

function runInThread(func, useAllCores = false, numThreads = useAllCores ? cpus().length : 1) {
    func()
}

let jobs = [
    job1,
    job2
]

jobs.forEach(job => runInThread(job))
```

Thus each worker will log:

```
job1
job2
```

and exits. Also since they are executed in two different processes, the log messages might be interleaved.